# Need the SQL query output to be like this

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

This is the query of my table

```
select Docno, quantity 
from ORDR
```

It gives the output like this

```
I330029 1
I330029 23
I330029 32
I330061 2
I330061 2
I330061 2
I330061 12
I330061 2
I330061 3
I330061 3
I330191 2
```

But I need the output like this if the doc no repeat the first value is "1" others "0"...

Like this:

```
I330029 1
I330029 0
I330029 0
I330061 1
I330061 0
I330061 0
I330061 0
I330061 0
I330061 0
I330061 0
I330191 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` on this. What it does is it creates a sequential number in every group. The outer statement test if the generated number is equal to `1` and if so, it will give it a value of `1` and the other is `0`.

```
SELECT  DocNo,
        CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END qty
FROM
        (
            SELECT  DocNo, Quantity,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DocNO ORDER BY Quantity) rn
            FROM    ordr
        ) a
ORDER   BY DocNo, qty DESC
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ed48e/2)